# how to join two tables in yii if i am querying a table using model and i don't want to use model for the second table?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Hi Guys i want to execute the following query

```
select tbl_workspace.wsName,tbl_cities.cityName  from tbl_workspace JOIN tbl_cities on tbl_cities.id = tbl_workspace.city WHERE active=1;
```

The method in the controller is as follows

```
public function actionWork(){
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->order = 'sorter';
        $criteria->condition = 'active=1';
        $criteria->join= 'LEFT JOIN tbl_cities on tbl_cities.id = `t`.`city`';
                    $workspaceList = Workspace::model()->findAll($criteria);
        $response=array();
        $workspace=array();
        $response['status']='True';
        $response['WorkspaceList']=array();
        if ($workspaceList):            
            foreach ($workspaceList as $row):   
                $workspace['id'] = $row['id'];  
                $workspace['wsName'] = $row['wsName'];
                $workspace['city'] = $row['city'];
                array_push($response['WorkspaceList'],$workspace);
            endforeach;
        endif;      
        echo CJSON::encode($response);
}
```

model for  table `tbl_workspace` is defined in the `Workspace` model But i haven't used any model for `tbl_cities` and i want to get this value 
`tbl_cities.cityName` , body of the method `actionWork` is defined in the controller and i want to query `tbl_cities.cityName`in my `$workspaceList` Object. please help me guys

Comment: `tbl_countries`  is not in your query

Answer (score 1):

You must use [Relational Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr) in yii. this is very simple and useful :

in models\WorkspaceList.php add:

```
public function relations() {
        return array(
            'cities0' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Cities', 'city'),
)
}
```

Create Model with CRUD generator for Cities.
for access to this field `$row->cities0->cityName` or  `$row['cities0']->cityName`

and in findAll:
`Workspace::model()->with('cities0')->findAll();`